# jQuery: How can I write val() of inputs to array elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I need to get coordinates of polygon from inputs: there is one input where I enter apex count of polygon. Then appear inputs (pair of coordinates for every apex). And there is the button, click on it must write X coordinates to array xCoords, and Y - to yCoords.

I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
var apexCount, xCoord, yCoord;

$('.js-apexCount').keyup(function() {
    $('.js-coordinates, .js-warning').remove(); //Remove fields for apex coordinates input if they exist
    apexCount = +$('.js-apexCount').val();
    if ( apexCount < 3 ) {
        $('#figureInfo').append('<p class="js-warning">It is not polygon!</p>');
    } else {
        for ( var i = 1; i < apexCount + 1; i++ ) {
            $('#figureInfo').append('<label class="js-coordinates"><input type="text" name="x' + i + '"><input type="text" name="y' + i + '">' + i +
             ' apex coordinates</label>'); //Add fields for apex coordinates input
        };
        $('#figureInfo').append('<button class="js-coordinates">Write down coordinates</button>')
    };

function getCoordinates() {
            $('[name ^= "x"]').each(function() {
                for ( i = 0; i < apexCount; i++ ) {
                    xCoord[i] = $(this).val();
                };
            });

            $('[name ^= "y"]').each(function() {
                for ( i = 0; i < apexCount; i++ ) {
                    yCoord[i] = $(this).val();
                };
            });

    };

$('button.js-coordinates').click(function() {
            getCoordinates();
            alert('' + xCoord + yCoord);
        });
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the data input? (small example)

Comment: @EWit, any numbers (1, 2, 3, 4 etc.), http://jsfiddle.net/hbzjctww/ - here something that it must look like

Comment: `xCoord` and `yCoord` are used like arrays, but they are not defined anywhere ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/hbzjctww/1/

Comment: @adeneo http://jsfiddle.net/hbzjctww/3/ In my code they are defined so. And your example works wrong(actually my example works wrong)=(

Comment: So why not post the code where you've defined them. The issue in the fiddle you've posted above is that the variables are defined as `undefined`, you haven't given them a value, and **they have to be arrays** if you're going to access them as arrays, and that means `var xCoords = [];`

Comment: OK, I understood) Thanks! But why does it write to array only last input values?